# Сделать выбор адресатов для рассылки email в форме обратной связи

Tags: php, javascript, post, форма, рассылка

Всем привет,
на сайте есть форма для отправки сообщения нескольким адресатам, для этого в php файле добавлены адресаты списком.
Задача:
Надо, чтобы в форме была возможность выбрать одного, несколько или всех адресатов из списка в файле php  .

```html
<form action="/sendemail.php" method="POST">
      <label for="tema">Заголовок:</label>
      <input maxlength="150" type="text" name="tema"/>
      <label for="message">Текст:</label>
      <textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="message"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="input-btn">Отправить</button>
</form>

<?php
       $tema = trim(strip_tags($_POST['tema']));
       $message= htmlentities($_POST['message']);
       if(isset($_POST['PERSONAL'])) ;

       if(!empty($error)) echo '<b>'.$error.'</b>';

       $subject = "$tema";
       $to = '01@site.ru'. ", " ;
       $to = '02@site.ru'. ", " ;
       $to .= '03@site.ru';

       $body = <<<HTML
<p>$tema</p>
<p>$message</p>

HTML;

       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
       $headers .= 'From: <info@site.ru.ru>' . "\r\n";

       mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

       header('Location: /');        

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="/sendemail.php" method="POST">
  <label for="tema">Заголовок:</label>
  <input maxlength="150" type="text" name="tema"/>
  <label for="message">Текст:</label>
  <textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="message"></textarea>
  <select multiple size="5" name="emails[]">
    <option value="01@site.ru">01@site.ru</option>
    <option value="02@site.ru">02@site.ru</option>
    <option value="03@site.ru">03@site.ru</option>
    <option value="04@site.ru">04@site.ru</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="input-btn">Отправить</button>
</form>

<?php
   $tema = trim(strip_tags($_POST['tema']));
   $message= htmlentities($_POST['message']);
   if(isset($_POST['PERSONAL'])) ;

   if(!empty($error)) echo '<b>'.$error.'</b>';

   $subject = "$tema";
   $to = implode(',',$_POST['emails']);

   $body = <<<HTML
<p>$tema</p>
<p>$message</p>

HTML;

   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From: <info@site.ru.ru>' . "\r\n";

   mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

   header('Location: /');        

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, почти то что я хотел. А как сделать чтоб чекбоксами отмечать или каждый отдельно или все вместе?

Comment: Попробовал данный способ в действии, не работает

Comment: <label for="emails-1">
                01@email.ru"
            <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" id="emails-1" value="01@email.ru">
        </label>
        <label for="emails-2">
                02@email.ru"
            <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" id="emails-2" value="02@email.ru">
        </label>
        <label for="emails-3">
                03@email.ru"
            <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" id="emails-3" value="03@email.ru">
        </label>

Comment: Это все конечно хорошо, но письма не отправляются. Открывается адрес http://site.ru/sendemail.php и на этом всё

Comment: в этой строчке ошибка была
$to = implode(',',$_POST['emails']);

Comment: Круть! Теперь работает, но только как выбрать сразу все?  По задумке будет около 200 адресатов и отмечать каждого, чтоб выбрать всех, это муторно. Пробовал сделать через этот скрипт http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/ASPUA/ но он почему то не хочет работать. Отдельно на чистом сайте работает, а на WP не хочет

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkash13/p3r1t8hm/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkash13/0fju9ekz/

Comment: благодарю за помощь! во всем разобрался и все работает. для работы в WP использовал эту статью https://mywpnote.ru/hitrosti-wordpress/wordpress-vstavka-javascript-v-zapis-ili-stranitsu/